# BigQuery Calculating Percent Overlap Between Values Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot-table, looker-studio

I am fairly new to SQL and bigquery and am working with a dataset of about 1.4 million rows.

The values of interest I have currently are category_name (string), item_id (string). What I am interested in doing is counting the distinct item_id's for each value in category_name (there are 269 total distinct values for this column). Basically in my base dataset, each row of data contains an instance of an item_id where it shows up in a single category_name, where an item_id can have multiple rows per day based on the number of category_names it appears in that day.

I've been able to run a successful query adding a new column for distinct item_id's for each value of category_name, now what the final output should be that I can't figure out how to do is calculate the percentage of distinct item_ids for 1 category_name that also appear in every other category_name. So basically I am looking for a new column (like a pivot table) that would count the matching item_ids for 2 category_names and then divide that count by the total distinct item_id's in 1 category_name. So essentially there would be 269 new columns for each category_name and each row would represent the percent overlap of the base category_name with every other category_name.

Here is the data in my table currently that I'm interested in

```
category_name  |   item_id
---------------|------------
category1      |  item1
category2      |  item1
category3      |  item1
category1      |  item2
category4      |  item2
category1      |  item3
category5      |  item3
category5      |  item2
category6      |  item4
category3      |  item5
category3      |  item6
category1      |  item6
category2      |  item5
category1      |  item4
```

Here is what my current query results look like

```
category_name  |  distinct_items
---------------|-----------------
category1      |  5
category2      |  2
category3      |  3
category4      |  1
category5      |  2
category6      |  1
```

Here is what I want the final output to look like:

```
category_name  | category1   |  category2  |   category3   |   category4   |  category5  |  category6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
category1      |   100%      |     20%     |      40%      |      20%      |     40%     |     20%
category2      |    50%      |     100%    |      100%     |       0%      |      0%     |     0%
category3      |    66.67%   |     66.67%  |      100%     |       0%      |      0%     |     0%
category4      |   100%      |      0%     |       0%      |      100%     |     100%    |     0%
category5      |   100%      |      0%     |       0%      |       50%     |     100%    |     0%
category6      |   100%      |      0%     |       0%      |       0%      |      0%     |    100%
```

Essentially the row values for category_name would be when that category_name is the target and comparing their total distinct_items to the other category_names and finding percentage of matches/total distinct_items based on item_ids. If there is another way to get this output without a pivot table that would be greatly appreciated as well. And there are 269 category_names and 6525 distinct item_ids for context.

If there is a simpler formula I can use in google data studio for this aggregation that would work as well because the final output in data studio should be a scatterplot with x and y axis the category_names and the bubbles be the % overlap so essentially just visualizing the pivot table results with a scatterplot. If anything in my description and question don't make sense or need more clarity please feel free to tag me and let me know what is confusing. Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

**Step 1** - Generate query text dynamically so you don't need manually enter all 269 categories ...

```
#standardSQL
SELECT '''SELECT category_name, ''' || 
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT
    ' MAX(IF(category_name2 = "' || category_name || '", percent, NULL)) AS ' || category_name
  ) || '''
FROM (
  SELECT t1.category_name, t2.category_name category_name2,
    ROUND(100 * COUNTIF(t1.item_id = t2.item_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT t1.item_id), 2) percent
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t1 
  CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table` t2
  GROUP BY t1.category_name, t2.category_name
)
GROUP BY category_name
'''
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If you run above against sample data in your question - you will get flattened version of below query

```
SELECT category_name, 
  MAX(IF(category_name2 = "category1", percent, NULL)) AS category1, 
  MAX(IF(category_name2 = "category2", percent, NULL)) AS category2, 
  MAX(IF(category_name2 = "category3", percent, NULL)) AS category3, 
  MAX(IF(category_name2 = "category4", percent, NULL)) AS category4, 
  MAX(IF(category_name2 = "category5", percent, NULL)) AS category5, 
  MAX(IF(category_name2 = "category6", percent, NULL)) AS category6 
FROM ( 
  SELECT t1.category_name, t2.category_name category_name2, 
  ROUND(100 * COUNTIF(t1.item_id = t2.item_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT t1.item_id), 2) percent 
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t1 
  CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table` t2 
  GROUP BY t1.category_name, t2.category_name 
) 
GROUP BY category_name
```

**Step 2** - Copy result of query in Step 1 and just run it as a query - that's it!

If you will apply this to sample data in your question - output will be

```
Row category_name   category1   category2   category3   category4   category5   category6    
1   category1       100.0       20.0        40.0        20.0        40.0        20.0     
2   category2       50.0        100.0       100.0       0.0         0.0         0.0  
3   category3       66.67       66.67       100.0       0.0         0.0         0.0  
4   category4       100.0       0.0         0.0         100.0       100.0       0.0  
5   category5       100.0       0.0         0.0         50.0        100.0       0.0  
6   category6       100.0       0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         100.0
```

Note1: You can automate whole above process using any client of your choice
Note2: I mostly worked out of data in your simplified example. in your real case you might need some minor adjustments - if you will have any issue with this - please post new question

Comment: hi thank you for your answer! I tried your method and the result I got was a single row and column with a bunch of information about the dynamic text for each column in the row. I tried saving this result to a table and running select * from that new table and nothing changed. please let me know if I have made some mistake in how I saved the result from step 1 to step 2. I also am wondering which tables you are referring to in t1 and t2 in your answer. please let me know and thank you very much!

Comment: also on line 3 where you say ' MAX(IF(category_name2 =

does that refer to the actual string value or is that in reference to just whatever the next value would be dynamically? because I'm not sure if you want me to put my value names in place of that or leave that as is.

Comment: 1) t1 and t2 are the aliases. 2) you should replace `project.dataset.table` with your table. 3) read again the answer. you should follow two steps as described - which is run Step 1 which will return one row with one column. Just copy the text within that column and paste it in Query editor and just run it! - let m eknow if more questions

Comment: one more time - the only what you need to do in Step 1 is to replace `project.dataset.table` with your own table reference. There are three instances that you need to replace there. Also, obviously this table should have `category_name` and `item_id` columns as it is stated in question - otherwise they also needs to be replace with correct column names. good luck

Comment: Ok that was all I was misunderstanding. The only problem now is that I am getting a syntax error: unexpected identifier "Hits" at [1:89]. I think the problem may be that this specific value string has a "!" in it, and I'm guessing that "!" can't be used in column names? Do you think that is the issue?

Comment: yes - `!` cannot be used in column names. If category values have category with `!` in ir - you should adjust the query to make sure you replace such not allowed characters with underscore for example. or just remove them! See Note2 in the answer

Comment: you can easily do this, by replacing second appearance of `category_name` in third line with something like `REPLACE(category_name, '!', '_')`

Comment: thank you so much. can you do OR statements here if there are multiple conditions I might need to replace? for instance i see one of the will be column names is just a number like "100" and I know that columns can't start with a number. Also some have spaces in the names.

Comment: instead of `REPLACE(category_name, '!', '_')` you can come up with any logic to suppress not qualified for column name chars and add let's say `col_` to the start to make sure you address all your cases. I think this is already enough helpful for you to vote up the answer and accept it as your original question is fully answered!

Comment: i finally got it to be valid on the second step, but while running it I got a query exceeded resource limits error. Do you know any way around this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213963/discussion-between-yaboy618-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Comment: Hello I am still not able to run this as the resource limits error won't allow me to complete the query. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.category_name,
       countif( t2.category_name = 'category1' ) / count(*) as category1,
       countif( t2.category_name = 'category2' ) / count(*) as category2,
       countif( t2.category_name = 'category3' ) / count(*) as category3,
       countif( t2.category_name = 'category4' ) / count(*) as category4,
       countif( t2.category_name = 'category5' ) / count(*) as category5
from t join
     t t2
     on t.item = t2.item
group by t.category_name;
```

This is simpler if you put the values in rows instead of columns:

```
select t.category_name, t2.category_name,
       count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by t.category_name) as ratio
from t join
     t t2
     on t.item = t2.item
group by t.category_name, t2.category_name;
```

Comment: thank you for the insanely quick answer. is there any way to alleviate having to write every single category name like with a mapping function of some sort for distinct category names? i will try this answer though and let you know if it gets what i am looking for. thank you so much!

Comment: @yaboy618 . . . If you put the values in rows rather than columns.

Comment: hey thank you again for this answer. i tried running this and i'm running into an issue because for category_name, some of them have duplicates so I'm getting the error "duplicate column names in the result are not supported." do you know any way around this?

Comment: @yaboy618 . . . There are no duplicate column names in this code.  The calculations should be only one per column_name.

Comment: I tried doing everything I could to alleviate possible issue by concat'ing another column value that differentiates some category_names so there are for sure no duplicates. Is there a way to check for duplicates or do you know any possible reason why I am getting this issue?

Comment: @yaboy618 . . . Perhaps you should ask another question.  This answer has no duplicate column names.